# How to input php echo outside of the php tag

Tags: php

I have this php code that input selected="" at a specific url. I need selected="" to in inserted into my html.

```
   <?php
    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if ( strpos($uri,'retailers/amazon/?sort=2') !== false ) {
       echo 'selected=""';
    } else {
       echo 'test';
    }
    ?>
```

This is the html, I need to insert selected=""... Something like this

```
<option selected="" value="retailers/amazon/?sort=2">Newest to Oldest</option>
```

...

```
<select onchange="window.location=this.value;">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option selected="" value="retailers/amazon/?sort=2">Newest to Oldest</option>
  <option value="retailers/amazon/?r_sortby=highest_rated&r_orderby=desc">Success Rate: High to Low</option>
  <option value="retailers/amazon/?r_sortby=highest_rated&r_orderby=asc">Success Rate: Low to High</option>
  <option value="retailers/amazon/?sort=0">Most Comments</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this...

```
<?php
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$sort2 = strpos($uri, 'retailers/amazon/?sort=2');
?>

<option <?php echo ($sort2 === false? '' : 'selected=""'); ?> value="retailers/amazon/?sort=2">Newest to Oldest</option>
```

Comment: Glad to help. Can you hit the check to mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to access the `echo` command outside the `php` tag and somewhere in `html`

it is not possible but there is an solution for this.

so you can try this option.

```
<select onchange="window.location=this.value;">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option selected="?php echo $uri?" </option>

</select>
```

its mean you are using the `php` code within the `html` area and you can access every variable of `php` by this.